# Need to delete native_splash_screen

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, flutter-dependencies

I added a native splash screen to the application, via the flutter_native_splash package. I uninstalled it, but it's not gone. What can be done?

I deleted it, but it's not gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add that `flutter_native_splash` library again to your dependencies.

And try running this: `flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:remove`